# How to create a shell script with the comand cal

Tags: shell-script, shell

I wanted to create a shell script that makes the user who executes this script when typing the month and year appear, but when doing so I get this error, can someone help me?

All this would be using the cal command

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
cal "" ""
echo  Write month and year
read cal
echo $cal
```

And this is the error

```
Write month and year
cal: year `' not in range 1..9999
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: well, you're passing `cal` two empty strings, which aren't valid years or months. I'm not sure what you're trying to do or expecting to happen here. If it's just reading the user's input and passing it to `cal`, it seems to me they could just run `cal` themselves, entering the months and years directly on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your script is actually doing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## Run the command 'cal' with two empty strings as arguments
cal "" ""

## print the string "Write month and year"
echo  Write month and year

## read whatever value was given into the single variable "$cal"
read cal

## print out the contents of the variable "$cal"
echo $cal
```

I think what you meant to do is:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Write month and year: " month year

cal "$month" "$year"
```

You would then run this as follows (in the example, the user entered `4` and `2020`):

```
$ foo.sh
Write month and year: 4 2020
     April 2020     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30
```

Of course, there doesn't seem to be much point in this, since you're not actually adding anything to the native `cal` command:

```
$ cal 4 2020
     April 2020     
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the year"
read y
echo "enter the month"
read m
cal -m $m $y
```

Tested and worked after using -m option Tested in ubuntu system

```
    January 2020      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
          1  2  3  4  
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
26 27 28 29 30 31
```